# Grepping with sed from start of the file to given parameter

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have a log, that i need to grep from time to time.
Problem is, the input may not be always correct, and there for when user enters start time, that is not correct, then nothing is grepped.

How can i implement a check, when no start time is set, then the file is grepped from the first line?

`sed -n '/1217-1337:37/,/&&&&-&&&&:&&/p' file.txt` is my original command

`&&&&-&&&&:&&` lets me grep until the end of the file, but in need to change starting point.

Example

```
row 1: 1111-1111:11 text
row 2: 1111-1111:11 text 
row 3: 1111-1111:11 text
```

Desired output when users inputs `sed -n '/1017-1337:37/,/&&&&-&&&&:&&/p' file.txt`

is that all 3 rows are returned to the user

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me perhaps you could give some sample input and desired output.

Comment: still not clear, give a bigger sample of good and bad entry and expected output. entered bad input may be in any form i supose and you say that there are only "bad". Criteria is in this case only 'no digit in "time" formated' or 'empty value' or other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your task right:

```
if -z "$START_TIME"
then
  sed -n '1,/&&&&-&&&&:&&/p' file.txt
else
  sed -n "/$START_TIME/,/&&&&-&&&&:&&/p" file.txt
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) Sorry for not approving the answer sooner